# Streaming Tweets to Console Using Flask

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask, kibana, tweepy

Using flask, I'm trying to:

- Get user input
- Filter a data stream based on the input
- Process filtered data
- Redirect result to Kibana dashboard for visualization

In `streamer.py`, I have a method `stream_tweets` which streams tweets based on an input.

When I run `streamer.py` using *python*, I'm able to get the tweets on the terminal, and view the visualization on the Kibana dashboard.

```
class Streamer():

    def __init__(self):
        self.twitter_authenticator = TwitterAuthenticator()

    def stream_tweets(self, hash_tag_list):
        listener = TwitterListener()
        auth = self.twitter_authenticator.authenticate_twitter_app()
        stream = Stream(auth, listener)
        stream.filter(track=hash_tag_list, is_async=True)

def main():

    tweet_streamer = Streamer()
    hash_tag = ['Arsenal']
    tweet_streamer.stream_tweets(hash_tag)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This file calls `listener.py`, which processes the data using the *textblob* library.

```
import json

from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from textblob import TextBlob
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

class TwitterListener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self):
        self.es = Elasticsearch()
        self.es.indices.create(index='twitter', ignore=400)

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            dict_data = json.loads(data)
            tweet = TextBlob(dict_data["text"])
            print(tweet.sentiment.polarity)

            if (tweet.sentiment.polarity == 0):
                sentiment = "neutral"
            elif (tweet.sentiment.polarity > 0 and tweet.sentiment.polarity <= 0.3):
                sentiment = "weak positive"
            elif (tweet.sentiment.polarity > 0.3 and tweet.sentiment.polarity <= 0.6):
                sentiment = "positive"
            elif (tweet.sentiment.polarity > 0.6 and tweet.sentiment.polarity <= 1):
                sentiment = "strong positive"
            elif (tweet.sentiment.polarity > -0.3 and tweet.sentiment.polarity <= 0):
                sentiment = "weak negative"
            elif (tweet.sentiment.polarity > -0.6 and tweet.sentiment.polarity <= -0.3):
                sentiment = "negative"
            else: # (tweet.sentiment.polarity > -1 and tweet.sentiment.polarity <= -0.6):
                sentiment = "strong negative"

            print(sentiment)

            self.es.index(
                index = "twitter",
                doc_type = "test-type",
                body = {
                    "author": dict_data["user"]["screen_name"],
                    "date": dict_data["created_at"],
                    "message": dict_data["text"],
                    "polarity": tweet.sentiment.polarity,
                    "subjectivity": tweet.sentiment.subjectivity,
                    "sentiment": sentiment
                })

            return True

        except Exception as e:
            print("Data Error:", str(e))
        return False

    def on_error(self, status):
        """Repeated access after rate limit will lock developer account."""
        if status == 420:
            return False
        print(status)
```

But when I call the same method from flask, the resulting template is rendered, but the tweets are streamed for a very short period of time - after which I get **Data Error: 'text'**

Below is the flask microservice:

```
@app.route("/dynamic-analysis/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def dynamic_analysis():
    tweet_streamer = Streamer()
    if request.method == "POST":
        hash_tag = request.form['dynamic_hashtag']
        tweet_streamer.stream_tweets(hash_tag)
        return render_template("query-dynamic-analysis.html")    # contains URL to Kibana dashboard
    else: # request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("dynamic-analysis.html")          # form to get user input
```

I've tried calling `render_template` with an additional *data* attribute which calls `tweet_streamer.stream_tweets(hash_tag)`, but I still get the same error.

How can I solve this?

---

**Update**:

I have also tried using `gunicorn` and `foreman` with the below configurations:

`gunicorn.conf.py`:

```
workers = 4
worker_class = 'sync'
loglevel = 'debug'
accesslog = '-'
errorlog  = '-'
```

`Procfile`:

```
flask_dynamic_analysis: gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:$PORT --config gunicorn.conf.py twitter_sentiment_analysis:app
microservices_routes: gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:$PORT --config gunicorn.conf.py app.routes:app
```

`.foreman`:

```
formation: flask_dynamic_analysis=2, microservices_routes=2
port: 3000
```

But still getting the same error.